# how to pass a channel with flexible length to a process in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I defined four boolean variables (bwa_flg, lariat_flg, gatk_flg, and deepvariant_flg) in nextflow.config.
Depending on the setting, I may have two bams (bam from bwa or/and lariat), two vcfs (vcf from gatk or/and deepvariant)
I need the bam-vcf pair to do the following analysis like phasing etc. (So I might have four pairs at most)
I tried these:

```
if (params.lariat_flg) {
   lariat(ch_reads).set{ch_lariatbam}
   if (params.gatk_flg) {
      gatk(ch_lariatbam)
      phase etc...
   }
   if (params.deepvariant_flg) {
      deepvariant(ch_lariatbam)
      phase etc...
   }
}

if (params.bwa_flg) { // also have to include gatk and deepvariant again from here because already used previously...
   bwa(ch_reads).set{ch_bwabam}
   if (params.gatk_flg) {
      gatk(ch_bwabam)
      phase etc...
   }
   if (params.deepvariant_flg) {
      deepvariant(ch_bwabam)
      phase etc...
   }
}
```

I have to write the following phase etc. four times, plus include these processes from modules four times.
how to do it smartly...

Comment: Why don't you assign the generated bam to a "bam channel" like `bam_ch` (instead of different channels for different bams) and use it for the other two conditionals (the vcf generation ones)?

Comment: @Poshi I thought of that. So I wonder how to pass a bam channel (which might have one or two bam, depending on the flag) to the next process.

Answer (score 0):

If the bams are coming from the same output channel you could use the `buffer` operator in the workflow declaration.

```
workflow example {
  main:
  bwa(input)

  if ( params.bwa_flg ){
    bwa
      .out
      .bwa_out
      .buffer( size: 2 )
      .set { bam_ch }
  } else {
     bwa
      .out
      .bam_ch1
      .flatten()
      .set { bam_ch }
  }
  deepvariant( bam_ch )
  ...
```

And if you need a flexible input for the process you can define a function.

```
process deepvariant {
  input:
  path(bams)

  script:
  def process_bams = bams{ "deepvariant --input $it" }.join('\n')
  """
  ${process_bams}
  """
}
```

But if they are coming from different processes, but they are from the same sample id, then you can merge samples based on the same if statement principles in the workflow declaration so long as you output tuples with sample id.

```
workflow example {
  main:
  bwa(input)
  lariat(input)

  if ( params.bwa_flg && params.lariat_flg ){
    bwa
      .out.baw_out
      .combine( lariat.out.lariat_out, by: 0 )
      .set { bam_ch }
  } else if ( params.bwa_flg ){
     bwa
      .out
      .bam_out
      .set { bam_ch }
  } else if ( params.lariat_flg ){
    lariat
      .out
      .lariat_out
      .set { bam_ch }
  }
  deepvariant( bam_ch )
  ...
```

`combine` will only work in this example if the outputs of `bwa` and `lariat` are something like `tuple val(sample_id), path(bam), emit: lariat_out`

Edit:
Here is the flexible deepvariant input, assuming multiple inputs are denoted each by `-i`:

```
process deepvariant {
  input:
  tuple val(sample_id), path(bams)
  
  script:
  def flexi_bams = bams{ "-i $it" }.join{' '}
  """
  deepvariant ${flexi_bams} -o ${sample_id}.output
  """
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think bam_ch would better receive from different processes, like the second way you provide, and then use combine. but in this way the length of bam_ch will be 2 or 3, depending on the flag. how does deepvariant define the input channel with flexible length?

Comment: Does deepvariant use all the bams together? If so it could be as simple as modifying the definition within the process. See the edit to the answer above.

Comment: no, deepvariant doesnt take two bams at one time. I want both lariat bam and bwa bam to run deepvariant separately. i.e., the deepvariant process take two channels and they run simutaneously (should I use transpose()?

Comment: You can either use the example in the original answer where I defined a flexible command using `def`, or potentially use the `concat` [operator](https://nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#concat).

Comment: @dthorbur can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304249/nextflow-module-compilation-error-in-the-process-script and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304098/nextflow-data-not-being-published-to-output-dir-after-process-is-complete